# Echoing 'at' command in terminal fails

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, at-job

The following should print "hello" (or some reminder) on my Linux command line at 9:00 AM today:

```
$ at 9:00AM
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> echo "hello"
at> <EOT>
```

However, at the specified time, nothing happens.

I have an empty `etc/at.deny` and no `/etc/at.allow` file, so there shouldn't be any problems with permissions to use the command. Also, writing a file at 9:00 AM works:

```
$ at 9:00AM
at> echo "hello" > /home/mart/hello.txt
at> <EOT>
$ cat /home/mart/hello.txt
hello
```

All jobs are shown as scheduled, I just can't get any output to the terminal window (I'm on Crunchbang Linux with Terminator). Why? Do I need to somehow specify the window for that output?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`at` runs commands from a daemon (`atd`), which doesn't have access to your terminal. Thus, output from the script isn't going to appear in your terminal (unless you pipe to the right `tty` in your command).

Instead, it does as `man at` says:

> The user will be mailed standard error and standard output from his commands, if any.

You may be able to access these reports using `mail` if your machine is suitably configured.

If you want to have `at` write to your terminal, you can try piping the output to `write`, which writes a message to a user's TTY, or to `wall` if you want to write to every terminal connected to the system.

Comment: That explains it, thanks very much! However, reading man pages for `write` led me to `wall`, which looks like the most straightforward solution for my purposes. Problem solved, see also next answer.

Comment: Yeah, I was just composing my solution as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, **nneonneo's** explanations led me to using `wall`, which sends a message to all users. So setting oneself reminders in a terminal window can be done like this:

```
$ at 9:00AM
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> echo "hello" | wall
at> <EOT>
```